# VBA- Transfer data from one sheet to another based on text and placing in into a specific location in the other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

[image: img1]

This would be the data, I would like to be able to take all the PP from sheet4 and paste them into sheet PDH_Handvoer in a specific range say A11:A22. Then also take the FA and paste them into the same sheet but with range A30:A42 and so one for each of the letters.

[image: img2]

so far this is the code, but it isnt doing what I need it to

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDH_Handover")

Dim LRow1 As Long, LRow2 As Long, i As Long
LRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LRow1
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "pp" Then
        ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, you just need to re-grab the `LRow2` value after you paste a new line - otherwise you're always overwriting your first line (and in you case, your last copied line is blank, so it *looks* like nothing is happening when it actually is).

I've also added `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to the end, as good practice (that clears the clipboard).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDH_Handover")

Dim LRow1 As Long, LRow2 As Long, i As Long
LRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LRow1
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "PP" Then
        ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Get new last row value
        LRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Rather, let's just get rid of `Copy/Paste` altogether, as it's best to avoid syntax that relies on `ActiveSheet`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDH_Handover")

Dim LRow1 As Long, LRow2 As Long, i As Long
LRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LRow1
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "PP" Then
        ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(LRow2 + 1, 1), ws2.Cells(LRow2 + 1, 4)).Value = _
        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 2), ws1.Cells(i, 5)).Value

        'Get new last row value
        LRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If we get the right value of LRow2 in the first time, I prefer to **LRow2 = LRow2 + 1**
but not to **End(xlUp).row**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LRow1 As Long, LRow2 As Long, i As Long

Set ws1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
Set ws2 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDH_Handover")
LRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
LRow2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

For i = 2 To LRow1
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "PP" Then
        ws1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 5)).Copy
        ws2.Range("A" & LRow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'Get new last row value
        LRow2 = LRow2 + 1
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Any idea how I would make it so that it would start appending onto A:11 vs just starting at A2 like it currently is?